# What is the main difference between MULE Studio and MULE ESB?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-esb

I am new in mule soft. i dont know what is the difference between mule studio and mule esb. both software are looking same only. mule studio is graphical representation as well as we can generate by code also. how can i differentiate both. what is the use of mule esb. where we can use the mule esb. how we can use this mule esb. i need exact difference between mule esb and mule studio. which one is best for integration.

Answer (score 1):

The mule Anypoint runtime/mule ESB is the core runtime. You need this no matter what for running Mule applications. Whether that is on-premise or Cloudhub it is using the mule runtime.

Mule/Anypoint studio is just for design/development time. It allows you to design and build your mule projects and run them for testing purposes using an embedded mule runtime.

Just like a Java web-app for example, you would develop in eclipse and test using an embedded Tomcat server for example but then you would take that app and deploy it to a dedicated application server for real use.

Same goes for Anypoint Studio. It cannot be used to run production applications. You need to take the application developed in studio and deploy it to a mule runtime setup such as on-premise or cloud hub etc.